# JSP how to Loop through an Array with Filters for unique objects?

Tags: java, database, loops, jsp

Hi all I'm hitting a bit of a snag on this project I'm working on.

I'm trying to make a list of unique list of objects(properties) and give them a list of features you can select from a database table.

this is the code for populating that database

```
  <% String selected_features = rz.fetch("real_estate", "selected_features");
                      %>

                      <input name="selected_features" type="hidden" value="<%=selected_features%>"/>

                      <rz:list module="estate_features" sort="seq_no asc" output="none" options="noscript" filter="">
                                    <%
                                        while(rz.listnext() && rz.listindex >= 0) {
                                    %><rz:listbody>
                            <div class="rz-checkbox">
                            <%
                              String featureName = rz.fetch("estate_features", "feature_text");
                              String recordid = rz.fetch("estate_features", "_recordid");
                              String selected = "selected_features_box";
                            %>
                             <rzt:checkbox
                               label="<%=featureName%>"
                               field="<%=selected%>"
                               checkedValue="<%=rz.fetch("estate_features", "_recordid")%>"
                                           target=""
                               checked="<%=("|"+selected_features+"|").indexOf("|"+recordid+"|") >= 0 ? "true" : "false"%>"
                             />
                             <%=("|"+selected_features+"|").indexOf("|"+recordid+"|") >= 0 ? "true" : "false"%>
                                             </div><!-- /.rz-checkbox -->
                          </rz:listbody>
                                            <% } %>
                                        </rz:list>
```

and this is the loop I've got going on the page

```
<rz:list module="real_estate" sort="seq_no asc" output="none" options="noscript" filter="<%="pageid=property-"+rz.pageid%>"><%
while(rz.listnext() && rz.listindex >= 0) {%><rz:listbody>

<%
    String features = rz.fetch("real_estate", "selected_features"); 
    String[] feature_arr = StringUtils.split(features, "|");
                                                   
    for (int i=0; i < feature_arr.length; i++ ) {   
        if(!feature_arr[i].equals("")){
        String feature_name = rz.fetch("estate_features", "feature_text", "", "_recordid="+feature_arr[i]);
%>
<li>
    <span><%=feature_name%></span> 
    
</li>
    <% } } %>
</rz:listbody>
    <% } %>
</rz:list>
```

as of right now the feature works when I make a single unique object. But when I make a second object it generates the entire list
[image]

The numbers are the features variable and are the recordid from a test I'm doing the first set 42|43|44|45|46|47|48|49 are for the first object while 50|51|52|53|54|55 are for the second object

Answer (score 0):

It's because your not setting a breakpoint for when it needs to end

```
for(int i=0; i < feature_arr.length; i++){
   if(!feature_arr[i].equals("")){
      String feature_name = rz.fetch("estate_features", "feature_text", "", "_recordid="+feature_arr[i]);
      this is what you need--->if(feature_arr[i] === feature_name){
```